# Need to do filter on nested field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I need to do filter on nested field with searchkick and from documentation I need to use 'price.currency' dot notation syntax to filter by nested field and it works when you need to use only one filter. But I need a little bit more complex real life filter: I need to filter by 'price.currency' AND 'price.amount' by amount in range. Fortunatly, I can do this with elastic 'nested' query but unfortunatly I can't find in amazing searhkick documentation way how to do it. I parsed searchkick source code and found that there are no way to use 'nested' command. Is there are a way to do it with searchkick or I am stupid that trying to use this library and ruby and rails and just need to go and die?

BR, Denis.

I read documentations, read source code and spend 2 days trying to find right solution.